# Problem in training a transformer implementation using tensorflow.estimator

Tags: python, tensorflow, attributeerror, transformer-model

The following colab url is a simple implementation of Transformer algorithm using Tensorflow.

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/10mvd_0PECxAeOeUbTEI-6NWfdOr0tVQM?usp=sharing

During the training stage, I get the following error message.

**---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 transformer.train(input_fn=lambda: train_input_fn(train_input_enc, train_output_dec, train_target_dec, batch_size), steps = epoch)

9 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in **getattr**(self, name)
441         np_config.enable_numpy_behavior()
442       """)
--> 443     self.**getattribute**(name)
444
445   @staticmethod

AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'value'

------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

I have spent hours to figure out what might be the problem, but I just can't.

Please help.

I have tried to examine the code thoroughly and searched on Google to find possible solutions without success.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. In particular, we're not going to go off-site to dig through your code on Google Colab. Questions must be self-contained. Please [edit] a [mre] directly into your question.